# Is it possible to use column indices in merge?

Tags: r, merge

If I have two dataframes that I wish to merge, is there a way to merge by the column index rather than the name of the column?

For instance if I have these two dfs, and want to merge on x.x1 and y.x2.

```
dtest <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10, y = 2:11)
dtest2 <- data.frame(x2 = 1:10, y1 = 11:20)
```

I've tried the following but I can't get it to work

```
xy <- merge(dtest, dtest2, by.x = x[,1], by.y = y[,1], all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

Comment: if there's a better function to use than merge for this use case, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Please include the desired result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
xy <- merge(dtest, dtest2, by.x = 1, by.y = 1, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

From `help(merge)`:  Columns to merge on can be specified by name, number or by a logical vector...

Comment: Actually vpipkt is it possible to use the join function in the plyr function?  Also could I join using two columns in each dataframe?  something like the following:

xy <- join(df1, df2, by = c(1,2), type = "inner")