# Recognizing synonyms in left_join in R

Tags: r, left-join, synonym

I have several quite large data tables containing characters, which I would like to join with the entries in my database. The spelling is often not quite right, thus joining is not possible.
I know there is no way around creating a synonym table to replace some misspelled characters. But is there a way to automatically detect certain anomalies (see example below)?

My data tables look similar to this:

```
data <- data.table(products=c("potatoe Chips", "potato Chips", "potato chips", "Potato-chips", "apple", "Apple", "Appl", "Apple Gala"))
```

The characters in my database are similar to this:

```
characters.database <- data.table(products=c("Potato Chips", "Potato Chips Paprika", "Apple"), ID=c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Currently if i perform a left_join only "Apple" will join:

```
data <- data %>%
  left_join(characters.database, by = c('products'))
```

Result:

| products | ID |
| --- | --- |
| potatoe Chips | NA |
| potato Chips | NA |
| potato chips | NA |
| Potato-chips | NA |
| apple | NA |
| Apple | 3 |
| Appl | NA |
| Apple Gala | NA |

Is it possible to automatically ignore: "Case letters", space" ", "-", and an "e" at the end of a word during left_join?

This would be the table i would like:

| products | ID |
| --- | --- |
| potatoe Chips | 1 |
| potatoChips | 1 |
| potato chips | 1 |
| Potato-chips | 1 |
| apple | 1 |
| Apple | 3 |
| Appl | 1 |
| Apple Gala | NA |

Any Ideas?

Comment: It is possible to join by column number instead.  This link may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117081/is-it-possible-to-use-column-indices-in-merge  Suggest you create a data.frame of column names so you can easily reference the column index number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Matt Kaye for your suggestion I did something similar now.
As I need the correct spelling in the data base and some of my characters contain symbols and numbers which are relevant I did the following:

```
#data
data <- data.table(products=c("potatoe Chips", "potato Chips", "potato chips", "Potato-chips", "apple", "Apple", "Appl", "Apple Gala"))
characters.database <- data.table(products=c("Potato Chips", "Potato Chips Paprika", "Apple"), ID=c("1", "2", "3"))

#remove spaces and capital letters in data
data <- data %>%
  mutate(products= tolower(products)) %>%
  mutate(products= gsub(" ", "", products))

#add ID to database
characters.database <- characters.database %>%
  dplyr::mutate(ID = row_number())

#remove spaces and capital letters in databasr product names
characters.database_syn <- characters.database %>%
  mutate(products= tolower(products)) %>%
  mutate(products= gsub(" ", "", products))

#join and add correct spelling from database
data <- data %>%
  left_join(characters.database_syn, by = c('products')) %>%
  select(product_syn=products, 'ID') %>%
  left_join(characters.database, by = c('ID'))

#other synonyms have to manually be corrected or with the help of a synonym table (As in MY data special caracters are relevant!)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd do a few things:

1. I'd strip all special characters, lower case all characters, remove spaces, etc. That'd help a bunch (i.e. potato chips, Potato Chips, and Potato-chips all go to "potatochips" which you can then join on).
2. There's a package called `fuzzyjoin` that will let you join on regular expressions, by edit distance, etc. That'll help with `Apple` vs `Apple Gala` and misspellings, etc.

You can strip special characters (only keep letters) + lowercase with something like:

```r
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

string %>%
  str_remove_all("[^A-Za-z]+") %>%
  tolower()
```